# Input submit with enter

Tags: javascript, input, submit

Is there a way to get an input to be submitted with enter via javascript? I couldnt find a solution. Sorry I'm a bit like a newbie. Thanks for your help!

```
<div class="ergonomierechner">
    <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 150%; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 5px;">Individueller Ergonomie-Rechner</p>

    <p>Deine K&ouml;rpergr&ouml;&szlig;e in cm:
        <input type="text" id="eing1" placeholder=" z. B. 175">
        <input type="button" value="Berechnen" onClick="ausgeben()">
        <br>
    </p>

    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <th>Tischh&ouml;he im Sitzen:</th>
        <th>Armlehnenh&ouml;he:</th>
        <th>Stuhlh&ouml;he:</th>
        <th>Tischh&ouml;he im Stehen:</th>
      </tr>
      <tr style="text-align: center;">
        <td><p id="tischsitzen"></p></td>
        <td><p id="armlehne"></p></td>
        <td><p id="stuhl"></p></td>
        <td><p id="tischstehen"></p></td>
      </tr>
    </table> 

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#eing1").keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      $("ausgeben()").click();
    }
});

function ausgeben(){

    var koerpergroesse = parseInt(document.getElementById("eing1").value)

    tischsitzen = koerpergroesse/2.43;
    tischsitzen = Math.round(tischsitzen);
    armlehne = koerpergroesse/6.75;
    armlehne = Math.round(armlehne);
    stuhl = koerpergroesse/3.72;
    stuhl = Math.round(stuhl);
    tischstehen = koerpergroesse/1.52;
    tischstehen = Math.round(tischstehen);

    document.getElementById("tischsitzen").innerHTML=tischsitzen + " cm";
    document.getElementById("armlehne").innerHTML=armlehne + " cm";
    document.getElementById("stuhl").innerHTML=stuhl + " cm";
    document.getElementById("tischstehen").innerHTML=tischstehen + " cm";

}

</script>
```

Is there a way to get an input to be submitted with enter via javascript? I couldnt find a solution. Sorry I'm a bit like a newbie. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Submit to where? Because I don't really see where you're submitting to. If you have a `button type="submit"` inside a `form` then it can submit with an enter without additional javascript

Comment: the 2nd input is the button with the function ausgeben(). 
 
thank you very much. I  changed the <input type=button> into <button type=submit></button>. Now it works without any extra js code, but it only appears for a few ms and disappears. If I press the button, it'll appear normally

Comment: just a note, `<input type="submit">` and `<button type="submit">` do the same things, except that with `input` it will also submit its value whereas with the `button` it won't. It really depends on what you want/need, but both work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap your `input`s with a `form` tag, you'll be able to achieve what you want without using JavaScript.

```
<div class="ergonomierechner">
    <p>Individueller Ergonomie-Rechner</p>

    <p>Deine K&ouml;rpergr&ouml;&szlig;e in cm:</p>

    <form>
        <input type="text" id="eing1" placeholder=" z. B. 175">
        <input type="button" value="Berechnen" onClick="ausgeben()">
    </form>

    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <th>Tischh&ouml;he im Sitzen:</th>
            <th>Armlehnenh&ouml;he:</th>
            <th>Stuhlh&ouml;he:</th>
            <th>Tischh&ouml;he im Stehen:</th>
        </tr>
        <tr style="text-align: center;">
            <td><p id="tischsitzen"></p></td>
            <td><p id="armlehne"></p></td>
            <td><p id="stuhl"></p></td>
            <td><p id="tischstehen"></p></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Also, in your function `ausgeben` you're defining several variables without using `var` and, because of that, you're polluting the global namespace. Do it like this:

```
function ausgeben() {
    var koerpergroesse = parseInt(document.getElementById("eing1").value)

    var tischsitzen = koerpergroesse/2.43; // Initialize with `var` keyword
    tischsitzen = Math.round(tischsitzen); // Reassign without `var` keyword

    var armlehne = koerpergroesse/6.75;
    armlehne = Math.round(armlehne);

    var stuhl = koerpergroesse/3.72;
    stuhl = Math.round(stuhl);

    var tischstehen = koerpergroesse/1.52;
    tischstehen = Math.round(tischstehen);

    document.getElementById("tischsitzen").innerHTML=tischsitzen + " cm";
    document.getElementById("armlehne").innerHTML=armlehne + " cm";
    document.getElementById("stuhl").innerHTML=stuhl + " cm";
    document.getElementById("tischstehen").innerHTML=tischstehen + " cm";
}
```

That way your variables `koerpergroesse`, `tischsitzen`, `armlehne`, `stuhl`, and `tischstehen` are declared within the scope of your function.

Here are a couple links about Scopes that can be useful:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)

https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript

Comment: thank you very much. I also change the <input type=button> into <button type=submit></button>. Now it works without any extra js code, but it only appears for a few ms and disappears. If I press the button, it'll appear normally

Answer (score 0):

You chould checkout Char Codes (Key Codes) :)

Enter is = 13 :)

something similair to:

Javascript

```
function submitForm(){
    document.formName.submit();
    document.formName.method='post';
}

document.onkeydown=function(){
    if(window.event.keyCode=='13'){
        submitForm();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried to implement your solution but sth. isnt working. Ive edited my post above. Could you maybe have a look on it please?

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, here is one of many ways to accomplish this:

```
$(".my_input_box").keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      $(".search_button").click();
    }
});
```